# Is it possible to define the settings of render datatable in shinny globally -- similar to what we do with themes in ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny, datatable

I'm a heavy R and Shiny user.
However, I don't know how to make my code easier to understand, as a big part of my shiny server code is something like:

```
output$t1_summary <- renderDataTable( {  table_somethign() }  ,
                                             options = list(pageLength = 100, dom = "t",
                                                            autoWidth = TRUE), rownames= FALSE )
```

I would like to know if there is a way to globally define these settings in my code.

Something in the same fashion that we do with ggplot, when we define

```
theme_set(theme_bw())
```

Thanks

Comment: If I wanted to "globally theme" `renderDatatable`, I would likely just write a wrapper function that sets defaults and options.

Comment: Could you please provide this code or something similar as a first start?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of a global theme, I'd probably just override the function with my own options.

```r
myDT <- function(expr, server = TRUE, env = parent.frame(),
                 quoted = FALSE, funcFilter = DT:::dataTablesFilter,
                 future = FALSE, ...,
                 options = list(pageLength = 100, dom = "t", autoWidth = TRUE),
                 rownames = FALSE) {
  DT::renderDataTable(
    expr = expr, server = server, env = env, quoted = quoted,
    funcFilter = funcFilter, future = future, ...,
    options = options, rownames = rownames)
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Just to clarify: After placing your code ontop of my r file, I need to use `output$all_summaries <- myDT( {   what_i_want() } )` instead of  `output$all_summaries <- renderDataTable( {   what_i_want() } )` . Is this the right way to do this? If so, R is saying that `data must be 2-dimensional`

Comment: You'd be getting that error of you used the original function, my function here is doing nothing to the table itself.